# failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxx" - Windows

Tags: postgresql, shell, pgadmin

I'm using Windows 8.1 PosgreSQL 9.5 and withn I try to exeucte `pg_dump` and asking for the password after I enter the correct password, I'm getting this error:
What do I need to do?

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "Nick" failed: FATAL: 
>   password  authentication failed for user "Nick"

I do not have database called "Nick" in my postgreSQL

Comment: Read the message. It's not a database named Nick, it's your login username. You're trying to authenticate with Postgres as a user named Nick. You probably have a specific postgres user account.

Comment: so how do i fix this error?

Comment: Hi Nick. pg_dump [connection-option...] [option...] [dbname] In your case --username= <username> --password <yourpassword> Ref http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html OR you could login as the super user for the posrgresql system